# Trigger action on Label change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm doing a website plugin by appending the block of my code on certain existing web page, which monitors the content change of certain web element on the existing page and trigger further actions on change.

As a plugin I don't want to modify the code block of the original page, I want to get the monitored element and register kind of "change event" on this element from my code block. For example

```
<html>
...
<body>
...
<label id="idLable">some text</label>
...

<!-- here begin my code block -->
<script>
var label = document.getElementById("idLabel")
label.addOnChange(function (oldValue, newValue)
{
    //do something
});
</script>
<!-- here end my code block -->

</body>
</html>
```

I googled for a long time, but didn't find the solution. Is there any possible to do that?

My Thanks,
Hai

Comment: There is mutation observer but forget about it, performance killer and random support. Better is to trigger a custom event when changing label text or just call a specific method. You should be able to extend plugin to add this behaviour. BTW, which plugin are you talking about? Maybe It already get inbuild method for that or exposes callback/event. One other way would be to extend specific jQuery method if jQuery is used by plugin to update label text

Comment: The plugin is what i am writing from scratch. Actually what kind of technology used on the target web page is not defined. The goal is, appending the plugin code on the target page, tell which element's content should be monitored and do something whenever the content changed.

Comment: Ok, i see. Well then try using mutation observer and equivalent on older IE browsers, see e.g this polyfill https://github.com/Polymer/MutationObservers  Or any other one for support IE<9

Answer (score 0):

There is no native function/option in JS.
But You can monitor the changes using setInterval function
Here is sample code :

```
var oldText=document.getElementById("idLabel").data;
var tmr = window.setInterval(function(){
if(document.getElementById("idLabel").data != oldText ) {


   //Your code goes here 


   window.clearInterval(tmr);
}
},1000);
```